# Android How to pass Firebase Database Reference to new activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-intent

I have 3 buttons in my activity and Im looking for a way to pass database reference via onclick to new activity, so it loads content from Firebase Database depending on button pressed.

Something like this:

- Button 1 pressed from Activity 1 > start Activity 2 & load data from Persons Reference > Person 1
- Button 2 pressed from Activity 1 > start Activity 2 & load data from Persons Reference > Person 2
- Button 3 pressed from Activity 1 > start Activity 2 & load data from Persons Reference > Person 3

I believe that I should use putExtra / getExtra to pass Intent. But how do I attach it to the specific node in Firebase Database inside new activity?

Comment: on button press sir you just pass the user id or reference id of the node to whose data you want to show on particular activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd typically pass *either* the key/ID of the selected person, or the *path of the node* in the database by [calling `toString()` on the `DatabaseReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#toString()). Based on this information you then construct a new `DatabaseReference` to the same data in the new activity. `DatabaseReference` objects are really lightweight, so the overhead of creating a new one is minimal.

Neither if these approaches is pertinently better than the other, and both work in similar situations, so it's down to personal preference which one you use.